# Changing font of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, fonts, uinavigationbar

**Solved**

By changing from "[UINavigationBar appearance]" to "self.navigationController.navigationBar" I was able to make changes to the instance itself and then it got loaded the first time as well

**TLDR;
UINavigationBar font not changing unless I load another view and then go back to the first view.**

Hi

I have an iOS7 project and I want to change the appearance of the UINavigationBar that I have embedded my project in.

I have done a little research, and I have found that if I want to change the font of the NavigationBar I will have to do this in the AppDelegate.m and in the method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

So I have created this code here:

```
- (void)changeAppearanceOfNavigationBar {
// Shadow
NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];

// Nagivation bar font
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],
                                                       NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                       shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,
                                                       [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:25.0],NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
NSLog(@"Font changed");
}
```

and I am calling this method from the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

So, this code does no do anything with the font, so I tried to do it in another way.

In my first view controller (the main app page) I do the same code in the viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],
                                                           NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                           shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,
                                                           [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:25.0],NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"TITLEEEE";

}
```

And here comes the "best" part of my problem. This code in viewDidLoad, does NOT change the font of my UINavigationBar at startup, BUT if I load another view and the segue back, it changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing from your code, these settings are performed on the class, not on an instance, which explains that it has effect afterwards, when you create a new instance.
When the applicationDidFinishLaunching is called the first instance of the bar has already been created, so making the setting then on the class is too late.
Try making this setting at an earlier point, e.g. even in your main(). This should be OK in this exceptional case that you are making a setting on a class and not on any instance.

Comment: Performing the code from viewDidLoad in my main had no effect :/

Answer (score 0):

Your attributes have wrong names, you need: UITextAttributeFont, UITextAttributeTextColor